# Correct use of SCOPE_IDENTITY function within simple stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'd like to simply send some information from a simple client to a log file and then use the identity created for further processing.

Is the following use of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` correct?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LogSearch]
    @userName       VARCHAR(50),
    @dateTimeStart  DATETIME        
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;


    INSERT INTO [WH].[dbo].[tb_Searches]
            (
            [UserName],
            [DateTimeStart]
            )
    SELECT  @userName, 
        @dateTimeStart;

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ProfileKey;

END;
```

**EDIT**

I've edited code to the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LogSearch]
    @userName   VARCHAR(50),
    @dateTimeStart  DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [WH].[dbo].[tb_Searches]
            (
            [UserName],[DateTimeStart]
            )
    VALUES  (@userName, @dateTimeStart);

    RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY();

END;
```

Comment: Looks OK. There are many ways to do this - using the return value, using an `output` parameter.

Comment: What are your specific concerns with this?

Comment: I'm building my first client-server application hence the basic question. This proc will be the first thing to run and the ID will then get passed down the line i.e. the ID will come back to the client and then get passed into 3 or 4 other stored procedures

Comment: I would normally use the return value, but there is nothing wrong with what you are doing. I would also use `VALUES` instead of the `SELECT` in your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: ok thanks as it is a single value using return would be an improvement

Comment: Side Note. I hate GUIDs, but GUIDs are useful for Primary Keys.  Especially CombGUIDS (http://trappedinhoth.blogspot.com/2011/07/remembering-combguids.html).  GUIDs you can create on the client side and pass them to your stored proc to use as an insert primary key.  That way you never have to worry about a stored proc returning the wrong primary key in a heavy use DB.  I think your Scope_Identity() usage is fine for 99% of the time,but just an FYI.There are even libraries out there to create SQL complaint GUIDs in Javascript, though for indexing it might be better to use a server side combGUID

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Seems like this is the best approach - can see a few references advising to only use `RETURN` as a way of communicating state or errors so an `OUTPUT` parameter is better practice:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LogSearch]
    @userName      VARCHAR(50),
    @dateTimeStart DATETIME,
    @searchID      INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [WH].[dbo].[tb_Searches]
                (
                UserName,
                DateTimeStart
                )
    VALUES  
                (
                @userName, 
                @dateTimeStart
                );

    SET @searchID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

END;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

is returning a `0` with Dapper.
I replaced it with

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

and now it is returning the actual value.

Comment: And that's the reason I usually use my own library... thanks Dapper for wasting my time.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in two separate statements, such as:

Assuming that the table has an identity field of course

```
Insert into [ABCTable]
([A], [B])
select 'WhateverA', 'WhateverB'
```

*Then* use the function `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in the `Where` clause, like:

```
Update [ABCTable] Set [A] = 'UpdateA', [B] = 'UpdateB'
Where IdentityField = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Thus, the scope_identity is a reliable link to the record just inserted.